# SailsJs - Joining multiple models with criteria on all joined models

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

Below is my data model,

**School:**

- SchoolID
- Name
- Status

**Game:**

- SchoolID
- GameID
- Name
- Status

**Participants:**

- SchoolID
- GameID
- StudentID
- Name
- Status

I want to show "Participants" based on "Status" of "Participants", "School" and "Game". Is it possible to filter results while retrieving?

Query i want to execute is,

```sql
select *
from
    Participants
    inner join Game on Participants.GameID = Game.GameID
    inner join School on Game.SchoolID = School.SchoolID
where
    Participants.Status="Active"
    and Game.Status="Active"
    and School.Status="Active"
```

How can i achieve it using sailsjs model association?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way in Sails.js/Waterline of populating deep nested associations yet.

You need set models like that:

Game:

```json
attributes:{
    SchoolID:{
        model: 'School'
    }
    // rest of attributes
}
```

Participants:

```json
attributes:{
    SchoolID:{
        model: 'School'
    },
    GameID:{
        model: 'Game'
    }
    // rest of attributes
}
```

Than query:

```js
Game.find({Status:"Active"})
    .populate("School",{
        where: {
            Status: "Active"
        }
    })
    .populate("Participants",{
        where: {
            Status: "Active"
        }
    }).exec(function (err, result){
        return result
    });
```

And now it's the tricky part. You will get Array with active games. Doesn't matter if they have active schools or participants. In result there will be 2 subarrays: Participants & School. If they are not empty thats your result.

```json
[
    {
        SchoolID: [],
        GameID: [],
        Name: '',
        Status: ''
    },
    {
        SchoolID: [SchoolID: 1, Name: '', Status: 'Active'],
        GameID: [SchoolID: 1, GameID: 1, Name: '', Status: 'Active'],
        Name: '',
        Status: ''
    }
]
```

You can use [lodash filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) to cleanup the results.

Second solution much simpler is use [.query()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)

You can just use your query that you wrote:

```js
School.query('select * from Participants inner join Game on Participants.GameID=Game.GameID inner join School on Game.SchoolID=School.SchoolID where Participants.Status="Active" and Game.Status="Active" and School.Status="Active"', function(err, results) {

    return results;
});
```

Comment: I want the participant result like below.
[{
      StudentID: 111111111,
      Name: Alex,
      Status: Active,
      SchoolID: {
            SchoolID : 2222222,
            Name: "St.Jhons",
            Status: "Active"
      },
      GameID: {
            SchoolID: 2222222,
            GameID: 3333333,
            Name: "Throw Ball",
            Status: "Active"
      }
}]
I should get Participant details only if Participant, and his Game & School is active.